# Gitlab CI & Code Climate JSON: Visualize results?

Tags: gitlab-ci, code-climate

After setting up Gitlab CI with its Code Climate integration, the CI pipeline generates a code quality report in the form of a JSON file.

Now I wonder: is there some kind of tool to visualize the report therein? Having to work with the raw JSON data is kind of clunky and prone to error.

It seems that there is some ongoing effort to add some functionality for this into Gitlab itself (i.e. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35929) but apart from that I couldn't find any tool for this?

Comment: Isn't the point of the CodeClimate integration that you *send that data to CodeClimate* for visualisation? For example https://codeclimate.com/github/textbook/fauxauth.

Comment: Which tool would be used to send that JSON there? How does that work with multiple branches? It seems like the current form of the GitLab JSON artifact is somewhat useless?